# What is the meaning of this NLP notation?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am learning NLP to try and do relation extraction on a corpus. I found [these](http://www.ryanmcd.com/courses/gslt2007/gslt2007.pdf) slides and am trying to parse the notation for a high-dimensional feature vector (shown below).

[image]

where

[image]

How do I turn the top most equation into an English sentence? For each input text unit, x ; for each possible feature, y -- the feature x is-a y can be represented by a feature vector? I am used to seeing cartesian product notation and I am used to seeing function notation and I am used to seeing set builder notation. But there are too many unfamiliar things going on in that line for me to understand what it says. What does the colon mean? What does the arrow mean?

Comment: i totally understand how you feel. the reaction should be "IKR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [function notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Notation). It says that there is a function f with a domain = X x Y and a codomain = R^n -- where X is some input text and Y is some label.

In other words, it maps each of all possible combinations of texts and labels and maps them somewhere into an n-dimensional space.

Answer (score 2):

That means that f is a function which takes an input and an output and produces a vector. In this context, the input is usually a word sequence, and the output a candidate labeling of that word sequence - e.g. a sequence of part-of-speech tags or a parse tree. There are some examples on slide 8 of Ryan McDonald's slide deck linked in the question.

McDonald makes this point too, but I'll repeat it here: In some cases, we can produce a feature vector purely from the input sequence (without reference to an output). E.g., if we're tagging word 2 of the sentence 'F is a function', and our feature mapping included only the current word and the previous word, we'd incorporate 'F' as the previous word and 'is' as the current word. But in some cases (notably 'structured prediction') we'll want to include features depending on a candidate labeling as well - perhaps a label sequence over the entire input (note that that will usually result in a *huge* feature space).

One other note: McDonald's mapping is to a real-valued vector (R^n), but in NLP, we often find that indicator features are sufficient, so many systems us a bit vector instead (still in a very high dimensional space). The formalism doesn't change (only the mapping function f), but the simplifying assumption will often allow efficiencies in the weight vector storage and dot-product implementation.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am a little hazy on what the colon means. And what the arrow means. Can you explain these symbols?

Comment: I believe the colon explicitly separates the name of the function (f) from the domain (input / output). The arrow denotes the mapping of the function from input domain to output domain - in this case, the input is the cross-product of X and Y, and the output is a real vector of m dimensions). That's simplistic and I'm sure it's not mathematically rigorous. But hopefully it communicates the idea.